# Python Django json serialise

Tags: python, mysql, json, django, serialization

I have a mysql objects.filter that I was trying to serialise to json. My fields are 
`domain, generated_on, id, priority_mx, record, record_points_to, ttl`

However, after I serialise the data like

```
from getdata.models import record_search
query_data = record_search.objects.filter(**filter_kwargs).only("domain", "record", "record_points_to", "priority_mx", "ttl", "generated_on")
data = serializers.serialize(lang, query_data)
```

my data has one additional field

```
model: "getdata.record_search"
```

I tried to remove it, by trying to select the fields as

```
 data = serializers.serialize(lang, query_data, fields=('domain','record_points_to'))
```

but `model: "getdata.record_search"` still remains in my serialised json data. What is the best way to exclude this?

As of now, since the serializers.serialize() returns a string, I am doing it as

```
return re.sub('\"model\"\:\s+?\"getdata\.record_search\"\,', "", data)
```

But I am sure this is an ugly way to do this. What is the pythonic best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialization is used for serializing/unserializing of **models**.  Django is unable to unserialize model without this "model" field.

Why you use serialization at all?  Why not use standard json library?

```
import json
from getdata.models import record_search

query_data = record_search.objects.filter(**filter_kwargs) \
                          .values("id", "domain", "record", "record_points_to",
                                  "priority_mx", "ttl", "generated_on")
data = json.dumps(list(query_data))
```

Comment: Thanks Catavaran. I was using serialize because, I pass json or xml or yaml through a query string, which I pass it on to serialize, rather than writing separate functions to achieve this. Looks like I'm gonna use your solution.